# Get the last updated row in an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I get the last updated row in an Oracle table? I have a table named Employees and I will perform some updates on it. Then I want to find out which row was updated last (i.e. which employee was updated last).

Comment: One good way to handle this would be to have a modified at timestamp column, which gets set whenever an update happens.  Then, you can simply filter using this column.

Comment: Do you have another solution? I don't think I'm allowed to use such a column.

Comment: Oracle doesn't track that kind of metadata by default. Similar to what TIm suggested, you could use a trigger and record changes in an audit table, rather than update a column on the actual table. The only other possibility would be to enable fine-grained auditing on the table and record all updates in the audit trail.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it by using a trigger and an audit table, please? I'm new in the oracle world.

Comment: @Anaidm,  I post an answer on how you can do it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way

- A table with a field name `updated` type `date`
- A trigger to update the column whenever any of the other columns are updated.

Then

```
SQL> create table test.t1_trigger ( c1 number, c2 number, updated date );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger test.t1_trg_update
before update of c1,c2 on test.t1_trigger
referencing new as new old as old 
for each row
begin
   :new.updated := sysdate;
end;
/  

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test.t1_trigger values ( 1 , 1 , null );

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> update test.t1_trigger set c1=2 , c2=2 ;

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test.t1_trigger ;

        C1         C2 UPDATED
---------- ---------- -------------------
         2          2 05.11.2021 12:18:30
```